# Python Script for selecting a Row of Vertices and applying 'Sort Elements'?

Tags: python, scripting

I have a number of Tiles resembling a Sphere.
[image]

In each tile, the Vertices are arranged in a different order, I want to rearrange them in a uniform order, like this,
[image: I want to arrange them like this]

So, the way I've been doing this is,

1. Select the first row of Vertices, Apply 'Sort Elements' - 'Selected'
2. Select the first two rows of Vertices, Apply again
3. Select the first three rows of Vertices, and so on...

But there are around 600 tiles, and doing each of them like this manually would be exhausting. I think Scripting would be ideal for this, But I don't know How to get the rows of Vertices, especially since I don't know the exact indexes of the Vertices that are in the first row.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110104/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79988/

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36619/15543   and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169097/15543  Easy enough to do in one fell swoop especially if looking at the spherical cube grid mesh.   A demo of the order required for  a 1 or 2 split cube would be handy. ie how to handle the order of common (cube) edges.